# MongoDB C driver _id generation

Tags: mongodb

I use mongo_insert() three times to insert my data in three different collections. The problem is that the "_id" field must be exactly the same in each of the collections, but I do not know how to (ideally) recover and reuse the "_id" field generated in my first mongo_insert...

Please, advice me how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you could have different field, like `CustomId` for your private needs, and leave `_id` for mongo generation.

But if you still need it to be exactly the same - there could be 2 variants:

1) setting custom generated `_id` do each doc.
2) Save first doc, then read it again, check it's `_id` and set it to the other docs.